# How to make assertions on a Laravel Mailable

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.5

In a test I would like to make some assertions on a Mailable using `Mail::assertSent()`, like this:

```
Mail::assertSent(MyMailable::class, function ($mail) use ($user) {
    return $mail->hasTo($user->email);
});
```

So far, I have found the `hasTo()`, `hasFrom()`, `hasBcc()` and all the other `has*()` methods work just great. However, when asserting a particular attribute on the Mailable exists, for example `subject` the attribute shows up as null and the assertion fails:

```
Mail::assertSent(MyMailable::class, function ($mail) {
    return $mail->subject === 'My Subject';
});
```

I believe this is because I have configured all of the Mailable attributes within the `build()` method which at the stage of the assertion probably hasn't been invoked, so the attributes are not set on the object yet.

I thought using the `build()` method was the correct approach to take based on the docs:

> All of a mailable class' configuration is done in the build method. Within this method, you may call various methods such as from, subject, view, and attach to configure the email's presentation and delivery.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#writing-mailables

I have found that I can get assertions on the Mailable's attributes working when I instead set the attributes on the constructor:

```
class MyMail extends Mailable
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->subject = 'My Subject';
    }

    public function build() {
        return $this->subject('My Subject')->view('emails/my-email')
    }
}
```

However, I feel this approach is wrong because I feel like I am changing my code to suit my tests.

So, I would like to know if there is a better approach to making assertions against attributes on a Mailable? Any help would be most appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT 1**

Test class (irrelevant code stripped out)

```
/** @test */
function a_notification_is_sent_when_an_application_is_updated()
{
    Mail::fake([RequiresVerification::class]);

    // some set up and factory methods called here...

    // the listener for this event sends mail
    ApplicationUpdated::dispatch($application);

    // this assertion passes
    Mail::assertSent(RequiresVerification::class);

    // this assertion does not pass when subject is set on the build()  
    // method but passes when subject is set on the constructor
    Mail::assertSent(RequiresVerification::class, function ($mail) use ($user) {
        return $mail->subject === 'hello';
    });
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I am currently looking at the [`hasRecipient()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L540), which all `has*` methods use, to see how it handles making assertions against what I assume are Mailable attributes (to, from, bcc, cc, etc). Perhaps the Mailable object can be extended to add new attribute assertions using a similar approach?

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailable.php#L540

Comment: Can you add the sample of your test file? Because actually in the test should invoking the send mail process. May be you can take a look at this documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking#mail-fake that is specific for Mailable testing

Comment: @DharmaSaputra code from test has been added. The mail process is invoked by an event dispatched in the test. I have looked at the docs but they don't explain how to make assertions against the Mailable's attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You can make assertions against attributes configured in the `build()` method by calling the `build()` method within the `assertSent` closure before making the assertions:

```
Mail::assertSent(MyMailable::class, function ($mail) {
    $mail->build();
    return $mail->subject === 'My Subject';
});
```

Thanks to @ohffs on laracasts for helping with this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/how-to-make-assertions-on-a-laravel-mailable